# JavaScript Module Pattern and HTML-Element Events

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, design-patterns, module

since a few days I working on getting the module pattern (with webpack) in JavaScript an TypeScript right. I know, I'm a little late for the party, but better now than never...

So far, I think I understood most of the best practices and their advantages.

As I'm working on a project that is a few years old, I wonder how the module pattern is used with events-listeners that are written in HTML like: 
`<p onclick="tooltip.open()"></p>`

What is the best practice for these situations in combination with the module pattern where I try to prevent polluting the global namespace?

Thanks for the answers in advance.

**Edit:**
I am especially interested in the best practice for webpack, as the webpack code bundle can only be accessed if it is build as a lib.
So how could event listeners in html access common JavaScript functionality if I use a webpack bundle?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to create modules. Here is one of them :

```js
/* modules/myModule/index.js */
const myModule = () => {
  // do cool stuff here !

    // Private methods here !
    function log(message) {
        console.log("message", message);
    }

    return {
        // Public methods here !
        open: () => {
            // do another cool stuff here !
            log("function open has been called!");
        },
    }
}

module.exports = myModule;


/* And then, in another file */
const myModule = require("modules/myModule");
myModule.open();
```

Comment: So if I have modules with basic functionality like tooltips, toasts or modal dialogs the preferred way to make the accessible by html-defined event listeners is to require/import the module into a global var/const?